# Want to make the li elements of ul list visible but not clickable using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue regarding how to make the 'li' elements of 'ul' list visible but not-clickable. I tried using ng-disabled directive to disable it i.e., not-clickable but it doesn't seem to work. Could please help me out in this issue which would be highly appreciable.

`Code Example (Plunker Link)`

Comment: Could you provide some of your code ? (An 'ul' for exemple) and be a little more specific about the behavior ?

Comment: The ul code is already there in the plnkr and behaviour is that the li element should be visible but one shouldn't be able to click the link i.e. it should be disabled. @Okazari

Comment: Didn't see the plunker, i made a proposition as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to prevent click events from registering on your `li`'s, you could implement this CSS rule:

```
li { pointer-events: none; }
```

If you need this to be dynamically set from Angular, consider using the core `ngClass` directive:

CSS:

```
.no-click { pointer-events: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-class="{'no-click': clickable}">No Touching!</li>
```

Sources:

- ngClass: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
- More info on `pointer-events` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events
- Reasonably supported in everything but IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

You can use this driective:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.widgets')
        .directive('zzDisableClickIf', disableClickIf);


    function disableClickIf($parse, $rootScope) {
        // Usage:
        //      <li>
        //          <a ui-sref="somestate" zz-disable-click-if="!model.isValid()">Go Somestate</a>
        //      </li>
        return {
            // this ensure zzDisableClickIf be compiled before ngClick
            priority: 100,
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function ($element, attr) {
                var fn = $parse(attr.zzDisableClickIf);
                return {
                    pre: function link(scope, element) {
                        var eventName = 'click';
                        element.on(eventName, function (event) {
                            var callback = function () {
                                if (fn(scope, { $event: event })) {
                                    // prevents ng-click to be executed
                                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                    // prevents href
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            };
                            if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
                                scope.$evalAsync(callback);
                            } else {
                                scope.$apply(callback);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    post: function () { }
                }
            }
        }
    }

} ());
```

This directives stops the action of  if `zz-disable-click-if='false'`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[])


app.controller("itemController",function($scope){
  $scope.condition=false;
  $scope.disableLink=function(){
    $scope.condition=!$scope.condition;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<html>
<style>
.not-active {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
 color: #ddd;
}
</style>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="itemController">
   <div >
    <ul class="list-group" >
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href='https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en'>Item1</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a ng-class={'not-active':condition} href='https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en'>Item2</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href='https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en'>Item3</a></li>          
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type='button' value='Enable/Disable Link' ng-click='disableLink()'>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just using ng-show / ng-hide to show an `<a>`or a `<span>` depending on the boolean holding the fact that the item should be clickable or not ?

That's not the sexiest, but it's still clean.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ctU41kgmgb66d1WGMsSv?p=preview) (i assumed your list is dynamically created but that's not something really important)

The HTML :

```
<ul class="list-group" >
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="list-group-item">
    <span ng-hide="item.clickable">{{item.name}}</span>
    <a ng-show="item.clickable" href=''>{{item.name}}</a>
    <button ng-click="item.clickable = !item.clickable">Disable/Enable</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I also added for the demo a button to disable/enable the link.

Tell me if what do you think about this solution.

Comment: @Prajwal Did you try my solution ?